# Decorator metaprogramming in javascript that doesn't involve repeating function names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, metaprogramming, decorator

Is it possible to write a name-preserving decorator in javascript that doesn't involve typing the name twice? I'm willing to use `eval` in strict mode, but not at the call site.

Trying to do something like:

```
@myDecorator
function myFuncWithANameICareAbout() {
    ...
}
```

There are various ways to do this. If I was doing this in the global scope, I could simply do:

```
function makeDecorator(decoFunc) {
    const decorator = function decorator(prewrappedFunc) {
        const postwrappedFunc = decoFunc(prewrappedFunc);
        window[prewrappedFunc.name] = postwrappedFunc;
        return postwrappedFunc;
    };
    window['deco_'+decoFunc.name] = decorator;
}

makeDecorator(
function myDeco(func) {
    console.log(`wrapping ${func.name}`);
    return function(...args) {
        //etc;
        console.log(`calling ${func.name}(${args.map(JSON.stringify).join(',')})`);
        return func(...args);
    };
});

deco_myDeco(
function helloWorld() {
    console.log('hello world!');
});

helloWorld();

// prints:
// wrapping helloWorld
// calling helloWorld()
// hello world!
```

The problem occurs if we're in the scope of a function, where we can't do `window[...] = etc` to define the function. We can't rely on hoisting, because function expressions are not hoisted! We'd have to do something like this:

```
function someFunctionScope() {
    const myHelloWorldFunctionWithANameICareAbout = myDeco2(function myHelloWorldFunctionWithANameICareAbout() {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Since we don't want to do something weird like make an phantom `this` extended with prototypical inheritance... and I do not believe this is possible without something like...

```
function someFunctionScope() {
    eval(myDeco2(function myHelloWorldFunctionWithANameICareAbout() {
    }));
}
```

Nor can we afterwards add a `function helloWorld() {}.postProcessWithDeco(...)` because that is against ecmascript syntax (and it would become a function expression even if it wasn't). So I'm just confirming that (unless the [decorator proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-decorators/) is accepted) this is currently impossible as of 2021? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with what most people usually do? Just return the decorated function. The decorator should ignore function names. Javascript functions are first-class objects just like integers, strings and numbers. Treat them like integers, strings and numbers - `let hello_world = decorator(function(){})`

Comment: That is what most people would do. My use case is basically https://stackoverflow.com/a/66417810/711085

Comment: @ninjagecko If your use case is to transpile code, why not go all in and use a transpiler in your build chain, with actual decorators (or whatever custom syntax you come up with to annotate your monadic functions) instead of trying to transform code at runtime?